# elasticsearch json array field

Tags: json, elasticsearch, apache-pig

My field in Elasticsearch is complex JSON array, please see the sample below

```
[
  {
    "row": [
      {
        "symbol": "777"
      },
      {
        "symbol": "555"
      },
      {
        "symbol": "Jack"
      },
      {
        "symbol": "Jack"
      },
      {
        "symbol": "Queen"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "row": [
      {
        "symbol": "Ace"
      },
      {
        "symbol": "Banana"
      },
      {
        "symbol": "999"
      },
      {
        "symbol": "Mouse"
      },
      {
        "symbol": "Milk"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "row": [
      {
        "symbol": "999"
      },
      {
        "symbol": "Ten"
      },
      {
        "symbol": "Mouse"
      },
      {
        "symbol": "Fish"
      },
      {
        "symbol": "Banana"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to either be able to write a query in Kibana to directly get an access to each count of `symbol` on each 'row':
or ideally I would like to write a correct es.mapping so I can read the data from ES in Pig script.

I tried the following

```
data = load 'my_index/my_type' USING EsStorage('es.query:?q=*', 'es.mapping.names=row:row') as (row:map[]);
```

it doesn't work, please advice.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, as row.symbol = '999' in Kibana.

So `row.symbol = '999'`will do the trick of counting all the documents that contain 999 symbol.